# Testing angular's $viewContentLoaded in watch

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

Can someone guide me how to test angular `$viewContentLoaded`. I have a `$watch` on this in my controller.

My relevant controller code:

```
$scope.$watch('$viewContentLoaded', function() {
            $scope.variableOne= true;
        });
```

Here is my relevant jasmine spec:

```
describe('Testing $viewContentLoaded', function() {
           it('should be true', inject(function ($controller,$scope) {
               $controller('MainCtrl');

              // what to do to invoke $viewContentLoaded ???

              $scope.$digest();
              expect($scope.variableOne).toBe(true);
           }));
        });
```

[Plunkr code](http://embed.plnkr.co/zMPHJl/)

Any help with this will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$viewContentLoaded` event get fired only when DOM gets loaded. So somehow you need to get DOM into a picture by assigning `MainCtrl` scope to it.

For that I'll say that add one dummy `div` with `ng-controller="MainCtrl"` assigned to it. Then compile that div with `MainCtrl` scope. So once you compile that div, after compilation of that div it will broadcast `$viewContentLoaded` will be listen by listener(that's why dummy DOM is important here).

**Code**

```
var $scope;
describe('Testing $viewContentLoaded', function() {
  it('should be true', inject(function($controller, $rootScope, $compile) {
    $scope = $rootScope.$new();
    $controller('MainCtrl', {
      $scope: $scope
    });
    var div = '<div ng-controller="MainCtrl"></div>'
    $compile(div)($scope);
    $scope.$digest();
    expect($scope.variableOne).toBe(true);
  }));
});
```

[**Demo Here**](http://plnkr.co/edit/Jd26BP?p=preview)

> **Note:**`$viewContentLoaded` event should be listen by placing listener over `$scope` like `$scope.$on` instead of putting watch over
>   it.

Comment: _Nice! This solution worked. Thanks._ Could you also tell me why do I need to create a new `$scope` from `$rootScope` for use with `$compile` and not just mock it?

Answer (score 1):

You can also do (assuming you have used $scope.$on instead of $watch for $viewContentLoaded):

```
$scope.$broadcast('$viewContentLoaded');
```

This prevents loading any DOM

Edit:
(To answer Basheer AL-MOMANI's question)

So, assuming `$scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded'` has been used instead of `$scope.$watch('$viewContentLoaded'`, you could call `$scope.$broadcast('$viewContentLoaded');` in your test. This way, there wouldn't be a need to load any DOM.

For ex.

In your controller, you could have:

```
$scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function() {
  $scope.variableOne= true;
});
```

And in your spec, you could test it like this:

```
describe('Testing $viewContentLoaded', function() {
  it('should be true', inject(function ($controller, $rootScope) {
    var $scope = $rootScope.$new();
    $controller('MainCtrl', {
      $scope: $scope
    });
    $scope.$broadcast('$viewContentLoaded');
    expect($scope.variableOne).toBe(true);
  }));
});
```

Comment: will you please elaborate, adding an example would be terrific